# Distances between coordinate pairs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

What is the best way to find the number of points (rows) that are within a distance of a given point in this pandas dataframe:

```
    x   y
0   2   9
1   8   7
2   1   10
3   9   2
4   8   4
5   1   1
6   2   3
7   10  5
8   6   6
9   9   7
```

The result (with distance=3) would look like this:

```
    x   y   points_within_3
0   2   9   1
1   8   7   4
2   1   10  1
3   9   2   3
4   8   4   5
5   1   1   1
6   2   3   1
7   10  5   4
8   6   6   2
9   9   7   4
```

More generally, I would like to understand how to compare rows in this way using `.transform()` or `.apply()`.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the distance matrix functions in [`scipy.spatial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve this using a lambda expression, but you can see that the scipy function is faster.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist

timeit df.apply(lambda x: sum(((x - df) ** 2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5 <= 3) - 1, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.34 ms per loop

timeit pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df))).apply(lambda x: x[x<=3].count() - 1, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment @jme.

This works:

```
df['points_within_3'] = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df))).apply(
    lambda x: x[x<=3].count() - 1, axis=1
)
```

But is it the best way to do this?